# Poor WiFi signal in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: wifi, ubuntu-18.04

I just shift to Ubuntu from Windows. Just after installing Ubuntu there "No WiFi adapter found" issue. I followed one [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dokG4bCF4GQ) video which fixed and helped to connect with the available wifi but, now I am having poor signal issue. I have also tried https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/ this answer and two three other answers from YouTube but no luck. What should I do get strong signal on my hp laptops?

Answer (score 0):

installing wifi driver works for me and I have tried this in many hp laptops and it works fine there as well.

https://github.com/kindlerprince/Wifi_Solution

```
statuscheck()
{
    if [ $1 -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo $2
        echo "Exiting...."
        exit 0
    fi
}

CURR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )
echo $CURR
echo -n "Enter the sudo password : "
read -s password

cmd=$(echo $password | sudo -S lshw -C network -short 2>/dev/null | grep Wireless | awk '{print $2 " " $4}')
if sudo -n true ; then
        echo "I got the sudo password"
else
        echo "Wrong sudo password"
        echo "Either replace the password in this script or give password via command line arguments"
        echo "Exiting...."
        exit 0
fi

#the return value is a single string having a space
#splitting by space and storing in a array
cmd=($cmd)
echo "Wifi Interface: "${cmd[0]}
echo "Wifi Driver: "${cmd[1]}

if [ -d "rtlwifi_new" ]
then
    rm -rf rtlwifi_new
fi

git clone https://github.com/kindlerprince/rtlwifi_new.git 
statuscheck $? "Failed to cloned Repository"


cd rtlwifi_new
make
statuscheck $? "Error occured in make"
sudo make install
statuscheck $? "Error occured in make"
sudo modprobe -rv ${cmd[1]}
sudo modprobe -v ${cmd[1]} ant_sel=2
sudo ip link set ${cmd[0]} up
sudo iw dev ${cmd[0]} scan
make clean

echo "Wifi Driver Installed Successfully"
```